Change of variable in conditional density function
I am reading a paper that makes the following argument:
Define $\psi_i := E[x_i | \mathcal{F}_{t-i}]$ and $\epsilon_i := \frac{x_i}{\psi_i}$, where we assume that $\epsilon_i$ is independent and identically distributed. Then the following holds:

$g(x_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}) = g(x_i|\psi_i)$;
$g(x_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}) = \psi_i^{-1} p(x_i / \psi_i)$, where $p(\epsilon)$ is the density of $\epsilon$.

As I understood it, the first claim is true because, intuitively, since $\epsilon_i$ is iid, once we know $\psi_i$ we already know everything that is relevant up to $(t-i)$ to determine $x_i$. However, I cannot understand where the fact in the second bullet point comes from. I guess it some kind of variable change but I cannot come up with any plausible explanation.

Some notation clarifications: assuming $\mathcal{F}$ is your filtration? What is $g$/what is known about it? $x_i$ is scalar?
